# I'm getting an error in the console 'PythonAnywhere'

Tags: connection, telegram-bot, pythonanywhere, openai-api

(venv) 12:12 ~/chatGpt $ python bot/main.py
2023-03-28 12:12:17,690 - telegram.ext._application - INFO - Application started

(here im sending text to my telegram bot and bot is answering = Failed to get response: ⚠️ An error has occurred ⚠️
Error communicating with OpenAI)

2023-03-28 12:12:24,197 - root - INFO - New message received from user @fr1day_pon
2023-03-28 12:12:24,991 - root - ERROR - ⚠️ *An error has occurred* ⚠️
Error communicating with OpenAI
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/irore6688/chatGpt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 980, in _wrap_create_connection
return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[return-value]  # noqa
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1064, in create_connection
raise exceptions[0]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1049, in create_connection
sock = await self._connect_sock(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 960, in _connect_sock
await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 500, in sock_connect
return await fut
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 535, in _sock_connect_cb
raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('52.152.96.252', 443)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/irore6688/chatGpt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 587, in arequest_raw
result = await session.request(**request_kwargs)
File "/home/irore6688/chatGpt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 536, in _request
conn = await self._connector.connect(
File "/home/irore6688/chatGpt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 540, in connect
proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
File "/home/irore6688/chatGpt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 901, in _create_connection
_, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
File "/home/irore6688/chatGpt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1206, in _create_direct_connection
raise last_exc
File "/home/irore6688/chatGpt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1175, in _create_direct_connection
transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
File "/home/irore6688/chatGpt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 988, in _wrap_create_connection
raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.openai.com:443 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('52.152.96.252', 443)]
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/irore6688/chatGpt/bot/openai_helper.py", line 133, in __common_get_chat_response
return await openai.ChatCompletion.acreate(
File "/home/irore6688/chatGpt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/api_resources/chat_completion.py", line 45, in acreate
return await super().acreate(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/irore6688/chatGpt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/api_resources/abstract/engine_api_resource.py", line 217, in acreate
response, _, api_key = await requestor.arequest(
File "/home/irore6688/chatGpt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 300, in arequest
result = await self.arequest_raw(
File "/home/irore6688/chatGpt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 604, in arequest_raw
raise error.APIConnectionError("Error communicating with OpenAI") from e
openai.error.APIConnectionError: Error communicating with OpenAI
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/irore6688/chatGpt/bot/telegram_bot.py", line 358, in prompt
async for content, tokens in stream_response:
File "/home/irore6688/chatGpt/bot/openai_helper.py", line 82, in get_chat_response_stream
response = await self.__common_get_chat_response(chat_id, query, stream=True)
File "/home/irore6688/chatGpt/bot/openai_helper.py", line 151, in __common_get_chat_response
raise Exception(f'⚠️ *An error has occurred* ⚠️\n{str(e)}') from e
Exception: ⚠️ *An error has occurred* ⚠️
Error communicating with OpenAI

I have not tried to solve anything yet so as not to break something in the code. I really need your help as this is for a presentation for my work about AI

Comment: It's very hard to read the logs. Could you isolate the problematic part?

Comment: Are you using a free account?  It may be related to the internet restrictions.